# string cannot be cast to integer

Tags: android, string, casting, int

I am new to using shared preferences and on my first try im getting errors that don't make sense to me. I assign a value like this:

```
int saveScore = sp.getInt("SAVE_SPOT",0); //This is intentional to get the 
                                          //default value of 0 to go to case 0


switch(saveScore){
     case 0:
           SharedPreferences.Editor edit1 = sp.edit();
           edit1.putInt("SCORE_1", score);
           edit1.putInt("SAVE_SPOT", 1);
           edit1.commit();
           break;
    case 1:
           int previous_score = sp.getInt("SCORE_1",0); // error happens here
           if(sp.getInt("SCORE_1",0)>score){

            SharedPreferences.Editor edit2 = sp.edit();
            edit2.putInt("SCORE_2", score);
            edit2.putInt("SAVE_SPOT", 2);
            edit2.commit();

             }
            else{

             SharedPreferences.Editor edit3 = sp.edit();
             edit3.putInt("SCORE_2", previous_score);
             edit3.putInt("SCORE_1", score);
             edit3.putInt("SAVE_SPOT", 1);
             edit3.commit();
                        }

        break;
```

Every time i run the program i get the error "string cannot be cast to integer". I am almost 99% sure the variable score is an int and not a string but I am not sure why i am getting this error.

Comment: The exception is thrown at putInt correct? Where are you assigning score?

Comment: the exception is on the getInt line. score is a variable that is updated as a button is pressed and then outside of the on click listener is where the shared preferences code is

Comment: Have a look at my solution. I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can check to make 100% it is an int by using this function:

```
public static boolean IsInteger(String s)
{
   if (s == null || s.length() == 0) return false;
   for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
   {
       if (Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10) < 0)
           return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

If `putInt` won't work, you could use `Integer.parseInt(` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue, un installing the app is necessary every time in testing because thats the only way to clear the stored data

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that you had a variable of that same name stored as a String, and you never cleared it. Docs say about `getInt()` "Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue. Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not an int."

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with `putInt()` it won't let you put anything but an int, so that is odd. Are you really telling the full story here?

My guess is that you have ANOTHER key that has the name `SCORE_1` that was actually stored as a string, and when you're grabbing out the int, it's picking up the String instead. That's the only way. According to the API:

```
Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not an int.
```

So I think `SCORE_1` is already in there, and was stored as a string. For the hell of it, try to get out `SCORE_1` using `getString()` instead.

See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: even when i tried this: String score1 = sp.getString("SCORE_1","0"); it says integer cannot be cast to string